# How to change the color of an elevated button when selected?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of buttons to choose from on the page and the user can select more than one. I want the button to change color when selected.

I've tried the following code, however, when selecting a button instead of that one button turning black, all the button options on the page turn black.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: you need to store the state of each button in a separate variable. Preferably use `List<bool>` instead of `bool _caBtnState`

Answer (score 0):

it's delicate
so save the elevatedButton value in a variable like _caBtnState and check the value not caBtnState